Dynamic calculation for columns in pandas
I have a data frame like
Bus_no.   City 
3412.     Kolkata 
7658.     Nagpur
3412.     Mumbai
5516.     Kolkata 
7658.     Chennai
3412.     Mumbai

I need to do a dynamic calculation based on these columns like for example bus_no.3412 is appearing in the whole dataset 3 times and appearing in kolkata 1time and Mumbai 2 times. So for 3412 in kolkata it will be = (1/3)*100 and for Mumbai = (2/3)*100.
Similarly I need calculation for each bus_no. In each city.
I am using python 3.6 .
Kindly help
So for 3412 in kolkata it will be = (1/3)*100 and for Mumbai = (2/3)*100.
Similarly I need calculation for each bus_no. In each city.
I am using python 3.6.
Output should be like:



Busno.
Kolkata
mumbai
Chennai
nagpur




3412.
Value
Value
Value
value



Kindly help

related https://stackoverflow.com/q/74413385/12846804

If you want to include all cities per bus (i.e. including the ones with 0%), you can use pd.crosstab with normalize='index', chaining df.mul and df.stack:
import pandas as pd

data = {'Bus_no.': {0: '3412.', 1: '7658.', 2: '3412.', 3: '5516.', 4: '7658.', 
                    5: '3412.'}, 
        'City': {0: 'Kolkata', 1: 'Nagpur', 2: 'Mumbai', 3: 'Kolkata', 4: 'Chennai', 
                 5: 'Mumbai'}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

out = (pd.crosstab(index=df['Bus_no.'], 
                   columns=df['City'], 
                   normalize='index')
       .mul(100)
       .stack()
       )

Output
Bus_no.  City   
3412.    Chennai      0.000000
         Kolkata     33.333333
         Mumbai      66.666667
         Nagpur       0.000000
5516.    Chennai      0.000000
         Kolkata    100.000000
         Mumbai       0.000000
         Nagpur       0.000000
7658.    Chennai     50.000000
         Kolkata      0.000000
         Mumbai       0.000000
         Nagpur      50.000000
dtype: float64


Edit: without chaining .stack() and instead chaining df.reset_index and df.rename_axis to get this in the desired format:
(pd.crosstab(index=df['Bus_no.'], 
             columns=df['City'], 
             normalize='index')
 .mul(100).reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None)
 )

  Bus_no.  Chennai     Kolkata     Mumbai  Nagpur
0   3412.      0.0   33.333333  66.666667     0.0
1   5516.      0.0  100.000000   0.000000     0.0
2   7658.     50.0    0.000000   0.000000    50.0


Alternative with df.groupby
Without needing all cities per bus, you could also use df.groupby and get the normalized value_counts:
out2 = df.groupby('Bus_no.')['City'].value_counts(normalize=True).mul(100)

Output alternative
Bus_no.  City   
3412.    Mumbai      66.666667
         Kolkata     33.333333
5516.    Kolkata    100.000000
7658.    Chennai     50.000000
         Nagpur      50.000000
Name: proportion, dtype: float64

But in that case, the answer by @mozway will be better.

Hi your first solution was very helpful for me. But I need the output as below

@CoderG: that's easy enough, just use the first solution, but without .stack() at the end. Adding df.reset_index and df.rename_axis. See the edit above.

@CoderG: Adding .reset_index().rename_axis(columns=None), I mean. Updated.

Yes got that thank you so much

Checking and finding NaN values in particular column in a pandas dataframe and log the null value in error log file in python .

You can combine different value_counts:
df[['Bus_no.', 'City']].value_counts().div(df['Bus_no.'].value_counts()).mul(100)

Output:
Bus_no.  City   
3412.    Mumbai      66.666667
         Kolkata     33.333333
5516.    Kolkata    100.000000
7658.    Chennai     50.000000
         Nagpur      50.000000
Name: count, dtype: float64


you can use groupby and size to count the number of occurences in the dataframe, then divide the counts you get
import pandas as pd

#setup, ignore this
bus = ["3412.", "7658.", "3412.", "5516.", "7658.", "3412."]
city = ["Kolkata", "Nagpur", "Mumbai", "Kolkata", "Chennai", "Mumbai"]
dfdict = {"Bus_no.":bus, "City":city}
df = pd.DataFrame(dfdict)

# code here
grouped_df = df.groupby(["Bus_no.","City"]).size()/df.groupby("Bus_no.").size()*100
entries = df.groupby(["Bus_no.","City"]).size()
counts = df.groupby("Bus_no.").size()
print(grouped_df)
print(entries)
print(counts)

# Bus_no.  City
# 3412.    Kolkata    33.3333
#          Mumbai     66.6667
# 5516.    Kolkata    100.0000
# 7658.    Chennai    50.0000
#          Nagpur     50.0000
# dtype: float64

# Bus_no.  City
# 3412.    Kolkata    1
#          Mumbai     2
# 5516.    Kolkata    1
# 7658.    Chennai    1
#          Nagpur     1
# dtype: int64

# Bus_no.
# 3412.    3
# 5516.    1
# 7658.    2
# dtype: int64

